# Sequelize, create new User and assign already created roles in one query?

Tags: database, express, sequelize.js, associations

Is it possible to create a user and set roles in sequelize like the code bellow or somehow without creating the user first and then setting the roles?

`User.create({name: ’test’, password:’test’, roles:[1,2] })`

Given the role ids 1,2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only create roles along with a user using one call. To assign existing roles to a user you need two calls:

1. to create a user
2. assign roles to the created user (calling a special method of the created user).

Anyway even if such a possibility exists technically it turns into two SQL queries. Don't forget to indicate the same transaction in both calls (1 and 2).

Comment: Thank you ! I knew I could make it work with two calls, but thought maybe there is a way to create and assigne at the same time. 
Thanks anyway !